# How do I have a loop create a function?

Tags: python

I have a project for a class and I am having trouble one part. So, I have defined three variables N, p, E. I create a loop for an index value of 10 times, where I want to set x equal to the equation below. However when I execute the module the loop prints the value obtained from the equation 10 times. What I want is for the equation to be evaluated, and then have that output be the NEXT N value, rinse and repeat (I want it like a mathematical function). How do I do this?

```py
def main():
    N, p, E = eval(input("Initial, probability, average"))  
    for i in range(10):
        x = (1 + E * p) * N 
        print(x)
            

main()
```

Comment: horrible idea to `eval` input immediately, remove that

Comment: Matiiss is right, first evaluate each input separately. e.g.
```python
N = int(input("Initial"))
p = float(input("probability"))
average = float(input("average"))
```
I guess instead of using 1, you want to use i.

Comment: Your function takes 3 inputs and produces 1 output.  How exactly do you want to run the output through the function to get a new value?

Comment: There's nothing in your code which creates a function (other than `def main():` which is not in the loop).

Comment: @Matiiss Why is it considered a bad idea to use eval input for all three variables In one statement?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/251345/the-perils-of-using-eval-for-dynamic-object-creation-is-this-a-valid-argume

Comment: @user796388 because it literally executes python code, which means that the user could input malicious code, basically bad practice, can lead to some other issues, better to use some string method like `N, p, E = (float(x) for x in input('Initial, probability, average').split(', '))` and it will return three float values if the user input them like this: `3.0, 5.4, 5.6`

Comment: It sounds like you want to use `(N + i)` instead of `N` in your calculation. That will use values from `N` to `N` + 10 as it goes through the loop.

Comment: It's also dangerous to use `eval` on input that you don't have complete control of. Users can provide inputs that crash your program or computer or take over your computer. The other comments give alternatives, or you could use something like this: `inp = input("Initial, probability, average").split(", ")` then `N = int(inp[0])` , `p = float(inp[1])` and `E = float(inp[2])`. Or you could use `N, p, E = [float(x) for x in input("Initial, probability, average").split(', ')]`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the value of N is to be updated with the x value, a while loop is used where the value is updated after each iteration.

```
def calculate():
    N, P, E = list(map(float, input("Initial, Probability, Average").split(" ")))  
    i = 0
    while i < 10:
        x = (1 + E * P) * N 
        N = x
        print(x)
        i+=1

calculate()
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you want to create would look like:

```
def f(initial, probability, average):
    return (1 + average * probability) * initial
```

To run this in a loop where each iteration updates the value of `initial` you might do:

```
i, p, a = map(float, input("Initial, probability, average").split())
for _ in range(10):
    i = f(i, p, a)
    print(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

### Hi I believe this is what you are looking for

#### if not please let me know

```py
def main():
    N, p, E = eval(input("Initial : ")), eval(input("probability : ")), eval(input("average : "))

    def _eval_equation(_x): return (_x + E * p) * N

    x = N
    for _ in range(10):
        x = _eval_equation(x)
        print(x)


main()
```

Comment: don't use `eval` and bold font without need

Comment: did not want to deviate from what the person who asked the question already knows, its always better to answer a question in terms the person asking you already know about.

Comment: no, not in this case, `eval` is too bad, there is a better alternative to it (from some built-in library that _could_ be used), but it should be avoided altogether, OP has to learn a better way anyways and the way you are showing it, could simply use `float(input())`

Comment: there are a thousand things wrong with that code, but you can't teach a thousand things at once.